# .htaccess issue with redirecting folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have a folder named /test in my application.

Right now i am trying to write an .htaccess file that would show all requests to /test* as /test.

For example:

www.example.com/test/ is the actual directory with index.php file in it.

All the requests like the following should go to the same /test directory

```
www.example.com/test-hello/
www.example.com/test-world/
www.example.com/test-htacess/
www.example.com/test123/
```

Basically any requests to /test* should go to /test.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
RewriteRule ^/test* /test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `RewriteCond` to first match "test in url"

Try below:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /test/
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) /test/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is wrong. You mean `^/test.*$`. Your rule would match to /testtttt.

The asterisk means that the char in front of it can be zero or more times included. The dot is a special char which means here could be anything. the `.*` matches every string including an empty string. See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 1):

You currently are not putting the `-hello`, `-world` etc behind your folder. What is `hello`? Is that the file? Or the param?

The second part of the rewriteRule should be a file. Something like

RewriteRule ^/test(.*)$ /test/$1.php

Above function will have:

```
/testABC to /test/ABC.php
```

But I don't understand what you want to accomplish?